# jQuery get prev or next item from selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this list of thumbs

```
<ul>
   <li class='thumb'></li>
   <li class='thumb chosen'></li>
   <li class='thumb'></li>
   <li class='thumb'></li>
</ul>
```

I also have navigation arrows, prev and next with classes 'next-image' and 'prev-image'. When i click on the navigation arrow i want to trigger click event on the prev or next thumb.

How can i target the previous or next thumb, from the thumb with class chosen.

```
$('.prev-image').click( function() {
    $('.thumb.chosen').prev().trigger('click');

});
$('.next-image').click( function() {
    $('.thumb.chosen').next().trigger('click');
});
```

This way it will search for following sibling with class chosen, but i need it to search the prev or next thumb from the thumb with class chosen.

Comment: Try quoting your attributes, and it probably solves a few issues.

Comment: can you create fiddle for your problem... it could help in solving your problem easily thanks.

Comment: forgot to quote it here, sorry, ill update

Comment: Your code will do exactly what you want

Comment: Where is your code failing? What does it do instead? Can we see *all* the relevant HTML (you seem to have forgotten to include the buttons). Are there any errors in the developer console? Can we see a (simple/[sscce](http://sscce.org)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes to your `class` attributes:

```
<ul>
   <li class="thumb"></li>
   <li class="thumb chosen"></li>
   <li class="thumb"></li>
   <li class="thumb"></li>
</ul>
```

I guess that `chosen` was interpreted as another attribute by browser.

### jQuery

```
$('.prev-image').click( function() {
    $('.thumb.chosen').prev().trigger('click');

});
$('.next-image').click( function() {
    $('.thumb.chosen').next().trigger('click');
});

$(".thumb").click(function () {
    $(".thumb").removeClass("chosen");
    $(this).addClass("chosen");
});
```

### CSS

```
.thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 5px;
}

.chosen {
    background: red !important;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kpUAf/)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add quotes in example here, that is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

here you can trigger the event as follows

HTML code :

```
<div class="prev-image">prev</div>
<div class="next-image">next</div>
<ul>
   <li class='thumb'>1</li>
   <li class='thumb chosen'>2</li>
   <li class='thumb'>3</li>
   <li class='thumb'>4</li>
</ul>
```

jquery :

```
// prev thumb trigering
$('.prev-image').click( function() {  
    var element = $('.thumb.chosen');

    $('.thumb.chosen').prev().trigger('click');
    $('.thumb.chosen').prev().addClass("chosen");
    element.removeClass("chosen"); 
});

// next thumb trigering
$('.next-image').click( function() { 
    var element = $('.thumb.chosen');

    $('.thumb.chosen').next().trigger('click');
    $('.thumb.chosen').next().addClass("chosen");
    element.removeClass("chosen");     
});

// trigger on click .thumb
$('.thumb').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    alert("triggered " + value);
});
```

CSS :

```
.chosen { color: red; }
```

**Implementation here** http://jsfiddle.net/jaJeD/